# Ways to a declare a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

Why does the following code compile:

```
int main()
{
   int j = 1;
   int *jp = &j;

   cout << "j is " << j << endl;
   cout << "jp is " << jp << endl;
   cout << "*jp is " << *jp << endl;
   cout << "&j is " << &j << endl;
   cout << "&jp is " << &jp << endl;
}
```

but not this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int j = 1;
   int *jp;
   *jp =& j; // This is the only change I have made.
   cout << "j is " << j << endl;
   cout << "jp is " << jp << endl;
   cout << "*jp is " << *jp << endl;
   cout << "&j is " << &j << endl;
   cout << "&jp is " << &jp << endl;
}
```

This compiles when I do `jp = &j`, why? I have only initialized `jp` in another line, this is not making sense to me.

Comment: What error are you getting when you compile?

Comment: prog.cpp:9: error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ result: compilation error

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies guys, ur answers really helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int *jp;
```

`jp` is a pointer. Its value (`jp`) is a memory address. It points to (`*jp)` an integer. When you do

```
jp = &j;
```

This sets the value to the memory address of `j`. So now `*jp` will point to `j`. When you do

```
*jp = &j;
```

This sets the value **of the thing `jp` is pointing to** to the memory address of `j`. When you do:

```
int *jp;
*jp = &j;
```

`jp` is not pointing to anything yet - its value is uninitialized. `*jp = &j` tries to follow the memory address of the value of `jp`, which is something random, and set it to `&j`... which will probably cause a segfault.

---

To clarify: The `*` in (`int *jp;`) is a different one than in `*jp = ...`. The former just declares `jp` as a pointer. The latter defines how you do the assignment. To make it even more explicit, doing:

```
int *jp = &j;
```

is the same as

```
int *jp; jp = &j;
```

Note there is no `*` on the assignment.

Answer (score 3):

```
*jp = &j;
```

This right here.  Take note of the `*`.  This goes and gets the data pointed to by the pointer, similar to what `->` does for objects.  What you're doing here is assigning a memory address to an int.  The pointer `jp` points to an int called `*jp`.

In short, `jp` is a pointer to an `int` (therefore an address) and `*jp` is the int that `jp` points to.  Using `&j` is getting you the address of `j`, or a pointer to it.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
*jp =& j; //this is the only change I have made,
```

Into this:

```
jp =& j;
```

That will make it compile.

The reason `int *jp = &j;` compiles is because it is declaring **and** initializing a value. In the **non-compiling** code, you are doing an **assignment**. And trying to assign an integer expression (`*jp`) to a pointer one (`&j`). Which doesn't make sense at all.

If you do:

```
jp = &j;
```

Then it will compile because you are assigning a pointer expression (`&j`) into a pointer variable (`jp`). There is type concordance in this case, so it makes sense it is compiling.

Comment: Yes I have noticed that but why is it?

Comment: @user1084113: I tried to elaborate a little bit more and updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`*jp =& j;` says "write the value of `&j` to the location that `jp` points to". This is wrong a) because `jp` doesn't point to anything and b) because `&j` is a pointer and the value that `jp` points to should be an int, not a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`int *jp = &j;` declares `jp` to be an `int*` (pointer to int), and initialises it with `&j` (the address of `j`).

`*jp = &j` dereferences the pointer to `j` (giving a reference to `j`), and then attempts to assign `&j` to `j`. This is illegal because `j` is an `int` and `&j` is an `int*`.

Answer (score 0):

You're parsing it in your head wrong.

The statement:

```
int *jp = &j;
```

really ought to be read as:

```
int* jp = &j;
```

Resulting in the actins:

- declare `jp` as a pointer to an integer
- assign the value of `&j` to jp

which matches the correction of your second code block:

```
   int *jp;
   jp = &j; // This is the only change I have made.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting tripped up by the difference between an *initialization* and an *assignment*; the two are different things.

The line

```
int *jp = &j;
```

declares `jp` as a pointer to `int` and *initializes* it with the result of the expression `&j`, which has type "pointer to int" (`int *`).

The line

```
*jp = &j;
```

attempts to *assign* the result of the expression `&j` (which has type `int *`, remember) to the result of the expression `*jp` (which has the type `int`<sup>1</sup>).  Since the *types* of the two expressions don't match, you get a compile-time error.

Note that the fact that `jp` hasn't been initialized to point anywhere meaningful yet would be a *runtime* error, not a compile-time error; IOW, if you had written `*jp = 5;` instead, the program would have *compiled* just fine (the expressions `*jp` and `5` have compatible types), but would have (most likely) blown up when you tried to run it.

---

<sup>1</sup> Declarations in C and C++ are based on the types of *expressions*, not objects.  For example, we're declaring `jp` as a pointer to `int`.  To retrieve the *value* of the integer being pointed to, we *dereference* the pointer with the `*` operator, as in the statement

```
x = *jp;
```

The type of the *expression* `*jp` is `int`, so the declaration of the pointer is

```
int *jp;
```